# How i can convert a mdb file to mysql file or mysql commands with PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, database, ms-access, jet

Is it possible to create mysql file or mysql commands from mdb (Microsoft access database) 2002-2003 format using PHP?

Actually i have a mdb file which have 8-10 table and i want to copy that whole data to my mysql database.
I know it is open question. Just need a starting point or if you can refer me some online helping material. That would be great. Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: Ugh, that sounds difficult. How about exporting to CSV instead?

Comment: Do you really need to use PHP for this? There are a number of programs you can download that will either convert a .MDB file into a .SQL file that can be imported by MySQL or it connects to MySQL and transfers the .MDB layout and data directly.

Comment: @iKnowKungFoo yes man, PHP is must.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U can use [ODBC](http://php.net/manual/en/book.uodbc.php) to connect to Access base, and make SQL queries.

Comment: This is a very broad answer... you sure it's your accepted best answer to your question?